# Filtering a Index view within ASP .NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, filtering

Is there a method to filtering a ASP .NET MVC 3 Index view?

I am thinking a search grid where you enter some parameters that then filter the indexs datasource.  In PHP world I would use $_GET or $_POST to retrieve the search parameter results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same in your index view.  You just need to accept optional parameters in your controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? param1, string param2, int? param3){
    //filter away
}
```

I usually setup a form on the view for the parameter entry, and then just change the `METHOD` to `GET` instead of `POST`.